# php - phantomjs alerts

Tags: php, phantomjs, phpunit

I am not very familiar with javascript and not sure how to handle alerts in php script when using phantomjs.

This is my code:

```
$this->clickcontrol(Constants::LINK, 'delete', false);
$this->acceptAlert();
```

So how should I change this to handle alerts in phantomjs

Comment: Your code is PHP but PhantomJS is a headless browser which uses JavaScript. Those two don't usually play well together. What is this using?

Comment: Basic idea of using Phantomjs is to run Headless testing. I do not see any issues combing the two except for the alerts. All my phpunit test cases work fine on phantomjs

Comment: PHP and PhantomJS don't play well together. You mention PHPUnit here as a comment but it's not obvious in your question that you are using this.  Are you also using a library that allows integration between PHPUnit and PhantomJS and if so which one?

Comment: From what I see, there is no need of any special libraries for this. All I have done is downloaded phantomjs, included that binary in my path and for browser, I mention phantom browser and set the desired capabilites like screen-resolution etc. I have nearly 50 tests and all run perfectly on phantomjs browser and the time needed is 75% less than running on an actual browser. The only test case that fails is the "alert" one and i see phantomjs does not handle that and we need a work around

Comment: In that case can you share the code for `acceptAlert` (I'm guessing that's the problem function)

Comment: I'm guessing this is some kind of selenium php binding but I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like PHPUnit's PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase.

When faced with this, I have created following function (I put it into a common base test case class myself, but it also can be in your test class):

```
protected function waitForAlert($expectedText, $timeout = 10000)
{
    $this->waitUntil(
        function () use ($expectedText) {
            if ($this->alertText() == $expectedText) {
                return true;
            }
        },
        $timeout
    );
    $this->acceptAlert();
}
```

Then in the test itself you can use it as such:

```
$this->waitForAlert('You need a complete profile');
```

If there is no alert it will fail after the timeout set

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks! that helps!